# getString() on static String to translate column database

Tags: android, database, string, translation

In the DB I have implemented in my Android App, some columns are designed to contain text in different languages, for example this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "food" (
    `_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `name_it`   TEXT,
    `name_rus`  TEXT,
    `description`   TEXT,
    `description_it`    TEXT,
    `description_rus`   TEXT,
    `kcal`  INTEGER,
    `icon_food` TEXT,
    `image_food`    TEXT,
    `category_id`   INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES category ( _id )
)
```

I want to use a static String to keep the name of the column, translated according to the language of the User's device

```
public static final class FoodEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(PATH_FOOD).build();

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "food";

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
        **public static final String COLUMN_NAME = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.food_COLUMN_NAME);**
        public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
        public static final String COLUMN_ICON_FOOD = "icon_food";
        public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";

        public static Uri buildFoodUri(long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    }
```

Here the string.xml

```
<string name="food_COLUMN_NAME">name</string>
```

This does not work because of the following error:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

How could I reach the goal to translate the column without touching more code? I wish to use a string resource that seems the perfect solution for my database structure

Comment: Do you have a resource called `food_COLUMN_NAME` in your `strings.xml` file ?

Comment: Yes I have it. The problem is with the static String

Comment: Did you read docs? *Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources **(no application resources)*** use translation table instead with pk id, translation_shortcut

Comment: What is a translation table?

Comment: Do not store `name` and `description` in `food` table ... make `food_translation` with `ID, lang, name, description` columns  then join it to food table like  `SELECT _id, name description, image_food, ... etc  FROM food f INNER JOIN food_translation ft ON  ft.ID = f.ID AND  lang=?` with parameter fx `"rus"` ...